# Insert simple XML list to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, insert

I'm trying to insert XML data into mysql database.  Issue I'm having is that there are multiple id's within each  tag so my script loads the first  only.  How do I re-write my script to load all id's to the db, one id per row.

```
<?php

 require_once 'db-functions.inc.php' ; //custom database functions

 $xmldata = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml?cursor=-1&screen_name=aplusk';
 $open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');
 $content = stream_get_contents($open);
 fclose($open);
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

 foreach ($xml->ids as $data) 

 {

 $id = $data->id;

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (id) 

 VALUES ('$id')");

 };


 // sample of xml I want to insert
 // <id_list>
 // <ids>
 // <id>275168965</id>
 // <id>28245852</id>
 // <id>15112249</id>
 // </ids>
 // <next_cursor>0</next_cursor>
 // <previous_cursor>0</previous_cursor>
 // </id_list>

 ?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `new SimpleXMLElement()` twice? also, as it would seem from the data, you need to `foreach` the `ids` element not the `id_list` for example: `foreach ( $twelement->id_list->ids as $data )` the `id_list` does in fact have just a single element in it as opposed to the `ids` element which contains the ids.

Comment: When I edit the foreach as above    foreach ( $twelement->id_list->ids as $data )  I get an error,  Is the insert statement correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you should do it:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( file_get_contents( 'http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml?cursor=-1&screen_name=aplusk' ) );
foreach ( $xml->ids[ 0 ] as $data ) 
{
    echo( $data . "<br>" );
}
```

It's not at all intuitive but the ids are hiding inside $xml->ids[ 0 ].
Your SQL statement seems fine.